# Are hatched Pokemon affected by the Halloween special spawn rates?

Tags: pokemon-go

Between October 26th and November 1st, Pokémon Go's Halloween special has increased the spawn rate of the following Pokémon:

- Drowzee
- Hypno
- Gastly
- Haunter
- Gengar
- Zubat
- Golbat
- Meowth
- Cubone
- Marowak

I started an incubation of a 5km egg around the same time the event started, and the egg finally hatched into a Meowth.

Before my egg hatched I incubated another 5km egg, and since [Eggs are predetermined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280932/are-eggs-predetermined-before-you-hatch-them), does my egg have a higher change of hatching one of the Pokémon with an increased spawn rate or are eggs not affected by the increased spawn rate?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence, but I have only hatched 2-3 tentacool, a clefairy, and a paras or two during this event.

Comment: Maybe edit your title to be more specific and match your real question within the body.

Comment: @Jerry I had planned on it, but life got in the way. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know (and confirmed by [this website](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/halloween/)) the only thing that is modified is the number of candies you recieve by hatching the egg (which the range is doubled).

Hatching a Meowth during the event was just luck (or badluck depending on how you see it).

---

So to your question : "Are eggs affected by the Halloween event?"

Yes, by doubling the range of candies they give on hatch.

Comment: When hatching an egg, the range of possible candies received has doubled.  I received an odd number of candy from an egg.

Comment: @Jerry this happened to me as well. 13 candy for a Magikarp.

Comment: added the specification, but yeah, I thought that doubled was clear enough to be the range. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

The species of the eggs which players had stockpiled prior to Halloween did not appear to be affected, in any of the numerous reports of hatch contents.

However: Eggs which were generated *during* the event were most assuredly affected by the spooky spawn table. Players who hatched many eggs ended up getting proportionally more Meowth and Ghastly.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to make their complaint?