# Do eggs acquired at a nest increase chance of hatching that specific Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

A few days ago, a few buddies of mine and I went out Pokéhunting to a Charmander nest that was close by. We spent roughly an hour in the vicinity and we all obtained 2 - 5 2km eggs. Over the next few days, we all spent the time to hatch the eggs we obtained and a majority of the 2km eggs we all received happened to be Charmanders.

As we see in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280932/are-eggs-predetermined-before-you-hatch-them) answer, eggs are predetermined when you obtain the egg, but it's odd how a lot of the eggs were Charmanders.

Do nests affect the eggs that are obtained in the area, or was this all a mere coincidence?

Comment: Who knows? (I'm really not that useful, am I ?!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a few threads (like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wjwys/theory_pokemon_eggs_may_be_influenced_by_the/), [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4w9yhy/eggs_hatch_and_pokestopnests_correlation/?ref=search_posts), or [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5u1aub/is_there_a_correlation_between_eggs_and_nests/)) discussing this possibility, but there doesn't seem to be enough evidence to be able to conclude if an egg obtained in/near a nest will have a greater chance of giving you a specific type of Pokémon. Some people claim that they hatch a lot of Pokémon similar to ones they were farming when they picked the egg up, others have seemingly random hatches. (I'm one of the latter)

Due to the amount of effort and data required to be able to prove this one way or another, it's not possible to say (yet), but it seems like a pretty safe bet that eggs are randomly distributed.